# ternary operator for a variable

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date field which returns '1970-01-01' for empty value. So I want to create a ternary operator for a variable `$from`.Still it returns 1970-01-01.What I did wrong

```
$from=$asset_other_details->start_date;  //1970-01-01
$from == '1970-01-01' ? '' : $from ;
```

Comment: check the exact text I given

Comment: You're not reassigning `from`

Comment: Do it in the assignment.

Comment: U don't have a condition at all in your statement.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly intuitive to use ternary operators where one of the cases is the initial value. This would be a lot more readable with a simple `if` statement.

Comment: @iainn Why not? It is just a shorthand `if`, that also is usually how it is used. (see example on the manual's page)

Comment: @chris85 Well strictly it's a short-hand `if/else`, and in cases where you don't need the `else` part then I don't really see the benefit. The accepted answer here contains a line that references the same variable three times, which (to me at least) isn't very readable. The newer short-hand operators `?:` and `??` were introduced to resolve this, although they don't apply to this case. All that said, I think I'm probably in the minority here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to assign new values to `$form` based on the comparison output like below:-

```
$from = $asset_other_details->start_date;  //1970-01-01
$from = ($from == '1970-01-01') ? '' : $from ;
```

Output to understand:- https://eval.in/867743

Answer (score 1):

you are not assigning the `$from` the new value. Try the following:

```
$from = ($asset_other_details->start_date == '1970-01-01') ? '' : $asset_other_details->start_date;
```